# let activity know when fragment is finished an operation

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, listener

I have an activity with two fragments.

Fragment A does a complex operation during onResume(), and Fragment B needs fragment A to be finished the complex operation, or else user interaction with Fragment B will cause a crash.

I want to put a progressbar spinning object in this activity until Fragment A is complete, and then reveal the layout with Fragment A and Fragment B side by side.

But I am unsure how to expose the completion of Fragment A's onResume to the activity.

In Fragment A I do have a `fragmentlistener` set up

```
public void onAttach(final Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    try {
        this.mListener = (TopicListener) activity;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(activity.getClass().getName()
                + " must implement TopicListener");
    }
}
```

But now what, thanks.

Comment: all communication between fragments should go through the activity and the activity delegates what fragment gets what information

Comment: @tyczj yes, but I don't know how to communicate the completion of individual operations

Comment: in the onResume just sent the callback to the activity, if this is in an asynctask then do the callback in the onPostCreate

Comment: @tyczj how does the callback to the activity work, example? can I pass variables in this callback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do this:

```
public class MyFragmentOne extends Fragment{ 
 @Override 
 onResume()
 {
   //Do the complex task
     ((MyActivity)getActivity()).fragmentTaskCompleted();
  }
 }


 public class MyActivity extends Activity
 {
  public void fragmentTaskCompleted()
  {
    //Show second fragment
   }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

As suggested on Android Developer [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#CommunicatingWithActivity), I would suggest you to not couple the fragments and use a callback through your activity class.

Comment: I realize this, I have unfortunately inherited code that I would like to fix without rewriting the whole thing

Answer (score 0):

Use your callback to send you to the activity.

Example of using callbacks with a map fragment

```
private MapListeners mLocation;

public interface MapListeners{
    public void onMarkerClick(Marker m);
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location);
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity){
    super.onAttach(activity);
    try{
        mLocation = (MapListeners)activity;
    }catch(ClassCastException e){
        throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString() + " must implement OnMarkerClick and OnLocationChanged");
    }
}

public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
//marker is clicked so send a call to the activity like this
    mLocation.onMarkerClick(marker);
    return true;
}
```

In the activity make sure you implement the interface, in this case it would be `MapListeners`

then when a marker was clicked the `onMarkerClick` method you created gets called

```
public void onMarkerClick(Marker m) {

    //do something
}
```